# Is there an option to turn a jQueryUI button into one that automatically disables itself when clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to prevent someone from clicking this button twice and triggering two form submissions which could result in duplicate payments on the server:

```
$("#SUBMIT_PAYMENT").button(
{
    label: "SUBMIT PAYMENT",
    text: true
});
```

Is there an option to make a jQueryUI button automatically disable itself after it is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with UI, but this might work:

```
$("#SUBMIT_PAYMENT").button(
{
    label: "SUBMIT PAYMENT",
    text: true
}).one('click', function() {
  $(this).button('disable');
});
```

Comment: I think you forgot the first argument for `.one()`: 'click'.

Comment: @WilliamNiu: My bad, sorry. Thanks for the fix!